# invalid identifier in sql oracle about between two date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote this query

and the system show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWtiF.png)

how to solve this problem ?

[The code should only show those data within the two date we enter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llVxt.png)

```
ACCEPT sDate CHAR FORMAT 'A10' PROMPT ' Enter the start date:  '
ACCEPT ednDate CHAR FORMAT 'A10' PROMPT ' Enter the end date:  '

SELECT s.customerID, c.fname, m.memberID, salesID, co.countriesName, p.productName,s.totalAmount,s.totalAmount*discountAmount AS subtotal,salesdate
FROM sales s, customers c, member m, list l, discount d, product p,shop sh,countries co
WHERE c.customerID = m.customerID AND
    m.memberID = d.memberID AND
    d.discountID = s.discountID AND
    s.listID = l.listID AND
    l.productID = p.productID AND
    s.shopID = sh.shopID AND
    sh.countriesID = co.countriesID AND
    salesdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(sDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(ednDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
order by customerID,salesdate;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Tip: Qualify all columns, at least when several tables are involved. (E.g. `s.customerID` instead of just `customerID`.)

Comment: What does the error message say? Doesn't it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

`sDate` and `ednDate` are being defined as [substitution variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-68AC9FF2-B92A-48D1-9699-133D47F8DDC1), so you need to change the references to be prefixed with `&`, and also enclose them in quotes:

```
salesdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('&sDate', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('&ednDate', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

If you don't quote them then it will try to do `TO_DATE(01/12/2022, 'DD/MM/YYYY')` which will error with ORA-01858.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running that in sqlplus or a PL/SQL development environment admitting substitution varaibles like sqlplus, then those substitution variables are to be preceded by `&`, like:

```sql
salesdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(&sDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(&ednDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: You also need quotes around the substitution variables (unless you expect the user to enter the quotes as part of their input).